# Convert a ul li to a list of strings c#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I get some text from some code I have no control over.

How do convert a html list to a List?

Suppose I have this

```
    string listItems = @"<ul>
                           <li> listItem one</li>   
                           <li> listItem two </li>      
                           <li> listItem Three.</li>
                        </ul>";
```

How do I convert it to a List of strings in c#?

Comment: Is it always this form? Or do you hhave to deal with other HTML fragments too?

Comment: no, seems to be always in this form. not very good on regex

Comment: RegEx looks easy, otherwise look up HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: cannot use html agility pack

Comment: why not? It's on nuget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex is not too hard:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(listItems, @"<li>(.*)</li>");
var items = matches.Select(m => m.Groups[1]);
```